# URL shortner checker should not check code formatted snippets

Tags: feature-request, code, content-blocklist, url-shortener

Today while trying to [salvage a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356166); I was prevented from doing so as the URL checker blocked the `bit.ly` URL.

The checker should ignore code snippets.

[image]

Comment: Ehh.. the URL isn't really important to the question here. If that endpoint is special, what's important is the *payload*, which should be included (or at least, the relevant parts) in the question anyway.

Answer (score 7):

There's currently no support for limiting a blacklist entry to not-code.

Arguably a better way to implement this would be to restrict the blacklist to *links* instead of URLs anywhere, but... There's no facility for that either at present.

OTOH, questions generally shouldn't rely on external resources to demonstrate the problem being asked about. Either `http://example.com/chiporders` works just as well, or the test-case will almost certainly fail in the future.